# Allow Component to Overflow to next line

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to get a map of a component to go to the next line (see yellow arrow). However, right now instead of going below it is squishing the Component (the Cards). I have made bg-colors to help assist. Any guidance would be great!

[image]

```
<div className="border-2 h-screen bg-pink-300 ">
            <div className="flex justify-end px-10 ">
                <button className="border-2 border-secondary p-2 rounded-lg hover:border-opacity-20">Add Item +</button>
            </div>
           
            <div className="flex overflow-x-auto bg-green-500 ">
            {data.map((data) => (
                <MenuCard title={data.title} ingredients={data. ingredients} 
                category={data.category} onSpecial={data.onSpecial} />
            ))}
            </div>
            
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `flex-wrap` class into the MenuCard's parent div element. Also remove the `overflow-x-auto` class as this will make the container scroll vertically.

Should look like this.

```html
<div className="flex flex-wrap bg-green-500 ">
  {data.map((data) => (
    <MenuCard title={data.title} ingredients={data. ingredients} 
    category={data.category} onSpecial={data.onSpecial} />
  ))}
</div>
```

You might also need to add `flex-shrink-0` class in each MenuCard instances if it tries to shrink.